# PHP - "bidirectional" recursive array_diff_key()

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I would like to apply **array_diff_key() recursively** on 2 multidimensional arrays and to find the difference between them.

It is important that the function will be "**bidirectional**" so **foo($a, $b)** and **foo($b, $a)** will produce the **same result**.

What I have tried? To be honest, I have tried too many things (including examples from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) and got lost.

```
function superMatch($a1, $a2) {

    foreach($a1 as $k => $v) {
        $r[$k] = is_array($v) ? superMatch($a1[$k], $a2[$k]) : array_diff_key($a1, $a2);
    }

    return $r;
}
```

**Input:**

```
$a = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => array('d' => 'd', 'e' => 'e'));
$a = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => array('t' => 'd', 'e' => 'e'));
```

**Expected output**: 't'

Can someone please give me a clue?

Comment: Please make a little example from input, current output from your code, and expected output.

Comment: Okay now we have your current code, but also add e.g. `Array1: [1,2,3,2], Array 2: [3,2,3,1,3], current output: xy, expected output: z` something like this.

Comment: Have you read all the answers under "Related" on the right?

Comment: The arrays are too big. I cannot copy-paste it. The expected result is array of key-value pairs of differences from the original arrays.

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing interesting.

Comment: Post a smaller dataset with your expected input/output. You can make up the data. Or try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php#111675

Comment: Here you go, I added example.

Comment: So, `$a['a'],$a['b'], and $a['c']['e']` all match. Shouldn't it output `Array['c'] = array( 'd' => 'd', 't' => 'd')`?... Because otherwise, the bi-directional abilities that you seek would be impossible, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you want recursive differences of keys that works bidirectionally, so given your input:

```
$a = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => array('d' => 'd', 'e' => 'e'));
$b = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => array('t' => 'd', 'e' => 'e'));
```

You should get the output:

```
$output = array('c'=>array('d'=>'d','t'=>'d'));
//or
$output = array('t'=>'d','d'=>'d');
```

The below method will return the first version of the output. But, you said in your question, that it should just ouput `t`, which wouldn't make sense because then it could not possibly work bidirectionally (since the key `d` also does not match).

```
/** return an array that contains keys that do not match between $array and $compare, checking recursively.
* It's bi-directional so it doesn't matter which param is first
*
* @param $array an array to compare
* @param $compare another array 
*
* @return an array that contains keys that do not match between $array and $compare
*/
function keyMatch($array,$compare){

$output = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
    if (!array_key_exists($key,$compare)){
        //keys don't match, so add to output array
        $output[$key] = $value;
    } else if (is_array($value)||is_array($compare[$key])){
       //there is a sub array to search, and the keys match in the parent array
        $match = keyMatch($value,$compare[$key]);
        if (count($match)>0){
            //if $match is empty, then there wasn't actually a match to add to $output
            $output[$key] = $match;
        }
    }
}
//Literally just renaiming $array to $compare and $compare to $array
// Why? because I copy-pasted the first foreach loop
$compareCopy = $compare;
$compare = $array;
$array = $compareCopy;
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
    if (!array_key_exists($key,$compare)){
        $output[$key] = $value;
    } else if (is_array($value)||is_array($compare[$key])){
        $match = keyMatch($value,$compare[$key]);
        if (count($match)>0){
            $output[$key] = $match;
        }
    }
}
return $output;

}
$a = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => array('d' => 'd', 'e' => 'e'));
$b = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => array('t' => 'd', 'e' => 'e'));
print_r(keyMatch($a,$b));
```

Oh, and here's an [example of it working](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1fa11abed7f583f90b3559a540e3601c5a01809d) on your small, example input.